# How can I append results from Python call to GUI in classes not in html using htmlpy?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am new to python and htmlpy. I have a python result and I want to output it in a particular class. At the moment I am doing the following:

```
           counter += 1
            roads = ""
            for m in suggestedroute:
                if suggestedroute is not 0:
                    output = "If you're taking Route " + counter.__str__() + " try to avoid: "
                    roads += m
                    if counter is not 1:
                        result += ". "+output + roads
                    else:
                        result +=output + roads

            self.app.html = u"<div style='color:red'> "+result+u"<div>"
```

Yet the result is overwriting the whole html page. How do I get it to be viewed in a div with a particular class?